# How can I merge two linked-list in C?

Tags: c, pointers, merge, linked-list

```
typedef struct Node{
    int val;
    struct Node *next;
}Node;

/* n1 and n2, head of two linked list */
void merge(Node *n1,Node *n2)
{ 
    Node *tail=n1;
    while(tail->next!=NULL)
        tail=tail->next;
    tail->next=n2;
}
```

I know this is completely wrong. But somehow, this makes sense to me. Probably, I misunderstood something with linked-list concepts. Can you please, explain to me in details, How can I properly merge two linked-list?

Comment: Well, it's how you wrote it, you are in the good way

Comment: How do you want to merge them? Is it that the two linked lists are sorted and the output should also be sorted? Or do you want to alternate the elements of the first list and the second list in the output? As it stands, the question is unanswerable because you haven't specified how the interleaving should be done.

Comment: I think he wants to add the second list at the end of the first one

Comment: Please provide details what exactly goes wrong. It looks perfectly fine to me. The code just makes the assumption that n1 is a non-empty list.

Comment: hmm I don't remember well, but is `struct Node *next;` correct in struct declaration ?

Comment: @Cid Yes, you are allowed to make a pointer to the same struct you're defining. You can't of course make an item of the same type.

Comment: @StereoBucket I know how linked lists work, I meant I don't remember having used `struct Node *next;` for next pointer but rather `Node *next;`

Comment: I don't want to just insert an element. There are two complete linked-list. I want to connect them. Let's say, in this example after the execution, I want n1 to continue until the n2's last element.

Comment: @Cid In C you're required to use `struct` before declaring a variable of struct type. Typedef is used to avoid having to do this, however the typedef is not visible inside of the struct in this case. You could go around that by doing `typedef struct Node Node;` and then defining your struct.

Comment: @AhmedSemihÖzmekik: concatenating the two lists is what your code does.  The only case it doesn’t handle is an empty list as `n1` — a null pointer.  That is not normally called “merging" two lists; that tends to imply comparing elements from each list before deciding which two put in the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
void merge(Node *first, Node *second){
    Node *third = NULL, *last = NULL;
    if(first->data>second->data){
        third=last=second;
        second=second->next;
        last->next=NULL;
    }
    else{
        third=last=first;
        first=first->next;
        last->next=NULL;
    }
    while(first && second){
        if(first->data<second->data){
            last->next=first;
            last = first;
            first = first->next;
            last->next = NULL;
        }
        else{
            last->next=second;
            last = second;
            second = second->next;
            last->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    if(first){
        last->next = first;
    }
    else{
        last->next = second;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).